# add '/' with second character in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Here i have a input field.

```
<input name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date" placeholder="MM / YYYY" class="form-control">
```

In this input when user write its card's expiry date then it should have a '/' append automatically after MM like **03/**.

I wrote a jquery code, in which / is appending but when i write the third character like 03/3 . But here i want it to append with the second character (like soon after 03).

```
 $('#expiry_date').keyup(function() {
        $('#expiry_date').attr('maxlength','7');
        var curr_val = $(this).val();
        var expiry_date = curr_val.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'');
        $('#expiry_date').val(expiry_date);
    });
```

JsFiddle link is down below:-
http://jsfiddle.net/fXnFF/2/

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply replace the requirement of having 3 numeric chars by only 2 and a single capturing group instead of 2 (**edited version**: finally made it with 2 capturing groups but the second one becomes optional):

```js
    
    $('#expiry_date').keyup(function(e) {
        $('#expiry_date').attr('maxlength','7');
        var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
        if( key != 8 ){
            var curr_val = $(this).val();
            var expiry_date = curr_val.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d*)?\//g,'$1/$2').replace(/^(\d\d)(\d*)?$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'');
            $('#expiry_date').val(expiry_date);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date" placeholder="MM / YYYY" class="form-control">
```

**EDIT** changed so that you can delete with backslash by testing key (only downside is that it will never reformat on backslash key).. also added another replace so that if you add number before an existing `/`, it gets reformated too (maybe that could be done in a single more complicated regex, but it's working)

Comment: your code works. But there is a problem. On putting the value 22 automatically ''/ " appends but when i hit i backspace i cannot delete the '/' infact  from second i can enter any number of characters like 22222222/ .

Comment: Probably worth adding the keycode for `Delete` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you always append a '/' after two characters are inputted wouldn't something simpler work?

```
$('#expiry_date').attr('maxlength','7'); // you only need to set this once
$('#expiry_date').keyup(function() {
    if(  $('#expiry_date').val().length == 2){
        $('#expiry_date').val($('#expiry_date').val() + "/");
    }
});
```

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/d1Lcwysa/4/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#expiry_date").keyup(function() {
  $(this).attr("maxlength", "7");
  var val = $(this).val();
  val = val
    .replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g, "$1/$2")
    .replace(/[^\d\/]/g, "")
    .replace(/^(\d\d)$/g, "$1/");
  $(this).val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date" placeholder="MM / YYYY" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetDate() {
$('#expiry_date').attr('maxlength','7');
var curr_val = $('#expiry_date').val();
var length =curr_val.length;
    if(length==2)
        {
         $('#expiry_date').val($('#expiry_date').val() + "/");
        }
```

}

```
<input name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date" onkeyup="GetDate()"  placeholder="MM /YYYY" class="form-control">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here faced the same issue . Couldnt delete '/'

Answer (score 0):

That Solve deleting '/'

```
function GetDate() {
$('#expiry_date').attr('maxlength','7');
var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
var curr_val = $('#expiry_date').val();

var length =curr_val.length;
    if(length==2 && key!=8 )
        {
         $('#expiry_date').val($('#expiry_date').val() + "/");
        }
```

}

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date"  onkeyup="GetDate()"  placeholder="MM / YYYY" class="form-control">
```